# Can HTML injection be a security issue?

Tags: security

I recently came across a website that generates a random adjective, surrounded by a prefix and suffix entered by the user. For example, if the user enters "123" for prefix, and "789" for suffix, it might generate "123Productive789". I've been screwing around with it, and I thought I might try something out. I entered this into the prefix field:

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">Click</a><hr />
```

And, sure enough, I was given the link, then an `<hr>`, then a random adjective. What I'm wondering is, could this be dangerous? There must be many more websites out there that have this issue, are all of them vulnerable to some sort of php injection?

Comment: Yes this is a major issue. Wiki page on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection and OWASP page on it https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection

Comment: It's actually the Javascript that's dangerous, as that is the part that can actually *do* anything.

Comment: @SystemDown but Javascript is client-side, correct?

Comment: @tkbx - That is correct. But it can still be dangerous. See the answer below on XSS attacks.

Comment: @SystemDown Well, if you can inject some Java applet in there and exploit a security vulnerability, that's pretty serious too. (Java might have some cross-site loading protection, which would mitigate this attack, though)

Comment: @luiscubal - Good point!

Comment: JavaScript isn't dangerous. It's trusting anything implicitly from the client-side that's dangerous. It does help as a stop-gap to escape potential risks in server-side data before injecting into HTML, however. None of this is really all that hard to maintain if you're bottlenecking data flow through one channel at key points and escaping/validating appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that this site is vulnerable to a [cross-site scripting attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS).  XSS is a reasonably common and potentially significant security vulnerability.

Of course, what an attacker can accomplish by using an XSS attack will depend heavily on the nature of the site itself.  An XSS vulnerability on a banking site is likely to lead to many more attacks than an XSS vulnerability on a toy web app that has no logins and has no user data.